# What encryption algorithm would be best for data transfer between Python and Php?

Tags: php, python, algorithm, security, encryption

I am writing a client / server based program, Server side is with Php and Client is with Python, and I need to make sure the transfer data is safe both way.

So, My question is

**What encryption algorithm would be best for data transfer between Python and Php?**

- I couldn't use **Https**
- Need to **decrypt/encrypt** with key on both Python and Php
- I would't need to have <s>shared</s> public key, key could be set in both Python and Php **manually**
- Since I don't know how to implement algorithm myself, **examples** on both language would be great.
- My data are not serious like banking site, but just want to encrypt to be safe on the wire from sniffing

I've tried to check this question but I couldn't find suitable answer for me

[Compatible encryption between C# and PHP, ColdFusion, Ruby, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/102496/compatible-encryption-between-c-and-php-coldfusion-ruby-python)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you use DES/DES3 or something like that?

Comment: yeah, anything if suitable, just don't know which one to choose and how to implement. Is DES3 public/private key based? I don't need to advertise public key, btw. I thought I could use AES, but I don't see those in standard Python packages.

Comment: Small note against bullet point 3: `key could be set in both Python and Php manually`. That *is* a shared key. Out of curiosity, why is SSL out of the question?

Comment: regarding SSL, because I don't have hosting with SSL support. And I meant, the algorithm does not have to be public/private key based, because I'm thinking like password protected data, and I could set that password in codes manually to do encrypt/decrypt processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is usually "it depends". If all you're looking for is symmetric encryption of sufficient quantities of data you'll probably want something like AES. There are however many ways in which you could use encryption that can turn out to be insecure in the end, which is why using https is a good idea since it's a bit higher level and harder to get badly wrong. I am not a security researcher, but this is just going on general advice I've been given in regard to security.

Anyways, there's a python library (edit: link removed, see comments) and you can apparently use [mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php) to handle encryption/decryption in PHP itself.

Comment: Just a couple points. Your encrypted data is likely to be 8bit. If you're doing small transfers, base64 encoding is probably easiest. If you are transferring a lot of data, you could stream the 8bit encrypted data with `transfer-encoding: chunked`, but you may need to jump through hoops to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks @MattH, but I couldn't set password in base64 btw. thanks for `transfer-encoding: chunked`, I need to learn that first. My data is not big though.

Comment: @S.Mark base64 is just an encoding, not an encryption. It lets you encode 8bit data over a transport that is not 8bit safe. I'm telling you this because the output from an encryption routine is likely to be 8bit. If, for example, you wanted to `POST` an AES encrypted chunk of data to your website, you'd need to use something like base64 encoding.

Comment: Thanks MattH, I've got it, for that case, I would like to do encrypt with AES first and like to do base64 encode. thanks for your help

Comment: This answer should be removed, or at least edited and marked as dangerously obsolete: as a matter of facts, the PyCrypto package to which the answer indirectly points is listed as having unpatched vulnerabilities by Github's scans.

Comment: @Gombo fair enough

Answer (score 4):

Do not attempt to invent an encryption scheme yourself. This is extremely difficult to get right (even professionals can't do this correctly on a regular basis). The SSL suite of security protocols embodies literally decades of research and implementation experience that you will not be able to reinvent.

For protection of private data over HTTP, the only correct answer is SSL. Anything else is doing yourself a disservice.

Comment: +1 thanks for pointing out, but I am afraid, I don't have SSL option in my hosting for now.

Comment: SSL and HTTPS are not the same thing.  If you can implement your own custom encryption scheme, then you also have all the tools you need to use SSL/TLS - and you certainly *should*.

Answer (score 1):

Greg Hewgill is correct and has the best advice. I tried to invent my own token system, while somewhat successful, it is not what it could be. So i believe SSL is the best way to go.

PHP has openssl built into it and such you can easily use that, which is what i am currently using. If you phone your hosting provider and ask them to enable openssl that shouldn't be difficult, that is if it is not activated already.

As for Python, im not 100% about what is available, but just to encrypt with a public key will be sufficient as your server will decrypt this data with a private key.

Public and private keys can be generated using your command line. Here is a link to that:

http://travistidwell.com/blog/2013/02/15/a-better-library-for-javascript-asymmetrical-rsa-encryption/

He does use a javascript library for client side encryption, however there should be options for Python.